# Display Image over map layer in GeoServer

Tags: image, dictionary, overlay, layer, geoserver

I am newbie when it comes to GeoServer and trying to figure out if there is an easy way to display images on top of map layer.

A background: In my application, based on a search criteria, some polygons are drawn on the map. Each polygon has a corresponding image (in TIFF format) that is stored somewhere. I want to load the image on top of the map when the user zooms in to a certain zoom level.

I know this can be done using openLayers but since my images are in TIFF format, (openLayers is not able to render TIFF images as far as i know) i have to convert them to .PNG first which would be very slow considering the number of images i have.

Hence I was wondering whether it would be possible to create a image layer that would retrieve an image of a certain polygon at a certain zoom level. If so, could anyone point me to an example or give me an idea on whether this is possible.

I am using spring 2.5, tomcat 5, java 1.6 and geoserver 2.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer's styling language, SLD, supports [using an image file](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/polygons.html#graphic-fill) to provide the fill texture when rendering polygons.  If the number of polygons that you want to handle is small, you could just set up a style rule for each polygon with its own image URL for the fill.  Otherwise, I'd recommend establishing a formulaic mapping from data attributes to image URLs, and using GeoServer's [dynamic symbolizer](http://blog.geoserver.org/2008/12/08/dynamic-symbolizers-part-1/) feature to reference the images.